# scala implicit passing to parameter

Tags: json, scala, implicit

To convert JsValue to custom Class, used this code.

```
def Foo(today : String):String = {
    implicit def read (js: JsValue) : Reads[ResponseBasicModel[String]] = Reads[ResponseBasicModel[String]](
      js => JsSuccess(ResponseBasicModel[String](
        ReturnValue = js.\("ReturnValue").toString()
        )
      )
    )

    CallAPI[ResponseBasicModel[String]](
        "GET",
        "URL"
        ,15.second).ReturnValue
  }
```

CallAPI :

```
def CallAPI[A](httpMethod: String, subURL: String, timeout: FiniteDuration)(implicit m: scala.reflect.Manifest[A], read: Reads[A]) :A = {
/...
     Json.parse(robots.toString()).as[A]
}
```

But It return error

> Error:(20, 47) No Json deserializer found for type
>   finance.remittance.data.ResponseBasicModel[String]. Try to implement
>   an implicit Reads or Format for this type.
>       return CallAPI[ResponseBasicModel[String]](

Is there any solution?

Comment: `return` is useless in functionnal Scala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved this problem with this code.

Writes is null because I do not use writes function.

```
def Foo(today : String):String = {
    implicit object ResponseBasicModelFormat extends Format[ResponseBasicModel[String]]{
    def reads(js: JsValue) =JsSuccess(ResponseBasicModel[String](
        ReturnValue = js.\("ReturnValue").toString()
      ))
    def writes(res : ResponseBasicModel[String]): JsValue=null
  }

    CallAPI[ResponseBasicModel[String]](
        "GET",
        "URL"
        ,15.second).ReturnValue
  }
```

Comment: I think you could just extend [Reads](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Reads) rather than `Format` with a dummy `writes` method.